# Css Table (display: table) with nested divs

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create a table layout using `display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` if **table-cell is not a direct child of table-row** ?

The example below would work if I remove the div with class `nestedDiv`, in such a way that the col divs are direct children of the row div.

Is this possible without altering the html structure?

```css
section {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

section .row {
  display: table-row;
}

section .col {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="nestedDiv"> <!-- nested div, this will not work -->
            <div class="col">Column A</div>
            <div class="col">Column B</div>
            <div class="col">Column C</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">1</div>
          <div class="col">2</div>
          <div class="col">3</div>
        </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it's tabular data should you not just use a table otherwise you are not really semantically correct and screen readers will have a tough time with it, but in answer to your question, no you can't have a nested div - it would be like putting a `div` in an actual `tr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Just set the `.nestedDiv` to `display:contents`

```css
section {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

section .row {
  display: table-row;
}

section .col {
  display: table-cell;
}

section .nestedDiv {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="nestedDiv"> <!-- nested div -->
            <div class="col">Column A</div>
            <div class="col">Column B</div>
            <div class="col">Column C</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">1</div>
          <div class="col">2</div>
          <div class="col">3</div>
        </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but it behaves unpredictably. table-cell elements on their own behave like inline-blocks however just wrapping one block with the display type table-row makes them behave like a table.

I use divs styled with table, table-row and table-cell elements sometimes to make responsive tables.

```css
.col {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class="col">Column A</div>
  <div class="col">Column B</div>
  <div class="col">Column C</div>
  <div class="col">Column D</div>
</div>
<div class="col">Column XXX</div>
<div class="col">Column YYY</div>
<div class="col">Column ZZZ</div>
```